# Erro react-native-gesture-handler na versão react-native 0.60.0

Tags: react, handler, native

Galera, tô com uma dificuldade com o React Navigation depois da última atualização do **React-Native** para versão **0.60.0**

O `react-native-gesture-handler` não é compatível por causa de um **autolink** que a versão nova do React-Native tem.

Já procurei em tudo quanto é fórum e não vi ninguém com a solução, pra fazer rodar meu projeto depois que instala o `react-native-gesture-handler`.

Eu fiz o seguinte, pra ficar bem explicado:

Eu criei o projeto com:

```js
react-native init PROJETO;
```

Instalei o react-navigation:

```js
yarn add react-navigation
```

<sup>(obs: tentei com NPM também)</sup>

Instalei o `react-native-gesture-handler`:

```js
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

<sup>(obs: também com NPM);</sup>

Linkei, conforme diz o manual:

```js
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Fiz as alterações necessárias no **MainActivity.java**, também conforme o manual.

Mas quando rodo o projeto:

```js
react-native run-android
```

Dá o erro:

```js
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following
  modules are linked manually:

react-native-gesture-handler (
  to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. 
Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it 
  will be included in your app automatically. 
If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify 
  the library maintainers.
```

Minhas dependências estão assim:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

Se alguém souber a solução, me ajuda, Vlw !!!

Comment: Não utilizo react-native, porem fiz uma pesquisa rápida e me parece que tem um request aberto para esse problema no [https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/671), nesse link também parece ter uma medida paliativa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O React-Native-Gesture-Handler suporta o autolinking no Android porém o problema se dá por conta que ele ainda não é compatível com o AndroidX.

1. Desfaça o Link (caso tenha feito) do projeto, manualmente

   `react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler`
2. Instale o Jetifier

   `yarn add jetifier -D ou npm install --save-dev jetifier`

   > O Jetifier (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jetifier) ajuda a tornar a biblioteca compatível com o seu projeto AndroidX convertendo todos pacotes de dependência em tempo de compilação.
3. Agora, abra o arquivo package.json do projeto e adicione essa linha na seção Scripts:

   `"postinstall": "npx jetify"`
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Agora execute o npm install ou yarn. Você irá ver algo parecido no console
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Faça os ajustes no MainActivity.java, confome o passos da documentação oficial https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html#android

FONTE: https://medium.com/@jeancabral/https-medium-com-rocketseat-usando-react-native-gesture-handler-com-a-versao-0-60-do-react-native-17b4ec8343bb

Answer (score 2):

Retirado do link: [How can I disable autolinking for unsupported library?](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-disable-autolinking-for-unsupported-library)

> #### Como posso desabilitar o autolinking de uma biblioteca não suportada?
>
> Durante o período de transição, alguns pacotes podem não suportar autolinking em certas plataformas. Para desabilitar o autolinking de um pacote, atualize a entrada `dependencies` do **react-native.config.js** para ficar assim:
>
> ```js
> // react-native.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   dependencies: {
>     'some-unsupported-package': {
>       platforms: {
>         android: null, // disabilitar na plataforma Android, outras plataformas ainda utilizaram o autolink se fornecido.
>       },
>     },
>   },
> };
> ```

Como eu disse no comentário da pergunta existe um request aberto para esse problema [https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/671).

<sup>Eu ainda não me aventurei nesse mundo do react-native, mas espero que os links postados aqui possa vir a te ajudar. =P</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Estava com esse mesmo problema. Tentei de tudo e nada funcionou, e o pior era a lentidão e o alto consumo de memória quando tentava dar o start.

A solução que encontrei foi voltar usar a versão 0.59.9, agora tá funcionando tudo tranquilo.

estou criando o projeto assim:

```
react-native init --version 0.59.9 nomeprojeto
```

Comment: Não funcionou assim também, infelizmente, vou tentar outras formas. Eu acho que quando instala a versão 0.59.9, outras dependências estão sendo atualizadas, e estão conflitando com o react-native-gesture-handler, além do React-Native.

Answer (score 2):

- **Para android**:
  Você precisa acessar a documentação da *lib* e configurar algumas coisas amais que tem. https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html#android
- **Para IOS:**
  Você precisa em um terminal do seu projeto, entrar na pasta `ios/` e executar `pod install`